# After changing grub timeout , to boot the PC doesnt reflects the changes done in the grub

Tags: grub2, grub-efi

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 I am not using windows anymore. I have been trying to change the grub timeout with success and update the grub afterwards. But when restarting the OS again , the time out is still 30 seconds when I have written 2 s.
I have tried also using the grub-customizer and still not helping.

Comment: So this is a Ubuntu Core 20 install?   Are you sure you ran the update grub script?

Comment: after you update the grub config file assure you run ... sudo update-grub .... to make it persist across reboots

Comment: It is done, but not working